# SSRS filter between two dates inclusive?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

There is existing data created between 2017-05-18 and 2017-05-18, when I run my report in CRM with those dates "From" "To", it does not return any data. Next in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio when I run my query with above dates it still dont return data, however when I add times to my query it then returns all the existing data for between '2017-05-18 00:00:00.000' and '2017-05-18 23:59:59.000'

How can I go about this in SSRS so it returns data from the same "From date" and the same "To" date? SSRS filter between two dates inclusive?

```
SELECT        
    Account.mm_registrationnumber AS CL_Reg_Number, 
    Account.Name, 
    Account.mm_supplierstatus AS Supplier_Status, 
    Account.PrimaryContactIdName AS Primary_Contact, 
    Account.EMailAddress1 AS Email, 
    Account.Telephone1 AS Telephone, 
    mm_address.mm_line1 AS Line1, 
    mm_address.mm_line2 AS Line2, 
    mm_address.mm_line3 AS Line3, 
    mm_address.mm_line4 AS Line4, 
    mm_address.mm_city AS City, 
    mm_address.mm_county AS County, 
    mm_address.mm_postcode AS Postcode, 
    mm_turnover.mm_name AS Signup_Turnover, 
    Account.mm_signupdate AS SignUp_Date, 
    mm_payment.mm_paymenttype AS Payment_Type, 
    mm_payment.mm_paymentstatus AS Payment_Status, 
    mm_payment.mm_vatamount AS Payment_Amount_VAT, 
    mm_payment.mm_paymentamount AS Payment_Amount_Net, 
    Invoice.InvoiceNumber AS Invoice_ID, 
    Invoice.DueDate AS Due_Date, 
    Invoice.CreatedOn AS Created_Date

FROM  Account 
    INNER JOIN mm_payment ON mm_payment.mm_organisation = Account.AccountId 
    INNER JOIN mm_address ON Account.mm_address = mm_address.mm_addressId 
    INNER JOIN mm_turnover ON Account.mm_turnover = mm_turnover.mm_turnoverId 
    INNER JOIN Invoice ON Invoice.AccountId = Account.AccountId

WHERE Invoice.CreatedOn between '2017-05-18 00:00:00.000' and '2017-05-18 23:59:59.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast your CreatedOn column as a date like so:

```
WHERE CAST(Invoice.CreatedOn AS DATE) BETWEEN '2017-05-18' AND '2017-05-18'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in SSRS?

Comment: or is there a way to do the above cast for any date which user selects from CRM report?

Comment: Yes just use parameters and then replace the date literals with the placeholder for your parametters.

Comment: I got this message Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string?

Comment: Is CreatedOn a datetime field?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use the time, Use Cast to  Cast your **DATETIME** field as a **DATE** field and it will pull all the records for that date.

```
WHERE Cast(Invoice.CreatedOn as DATE)  between '2017-05-18' and '2017-05-18'
```

If you do need the Time, Default your Date/Time Parameters to

```
=NOW()
```

and it will display Time in the Parameter.[image: Time]

Comment: is there a way to do this in SSRS?

Comment: how can I do this for every date and not only '2017-05-18'

Comment: Change '2017-05-18'  to  @ StartDate and the next to @ EndDate.

Comment: I got this message Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` without a space in between.Then make sure you report parameters are set to be a date type.

Comment: @AlanSchofield i got this message when I did that Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Can you update your post to show a sample of the data from the dataset with NO WHERE clause. And then a screen shot of the report design. Finally post your dataset query. This should be simple so you must be doing something basic incorrectly but without seeing what you are doing it's hard to help.